# How to loop the execution of a script on selenium?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Need help from the community. I'm new to Python and don't understand how to loop the execution of a `selenium` script.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.Firefox()

def change_password():
    driver.get("http://nsagov.ru/Users/Login.aspx")
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/form/div[4]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr/td/div/table/tbody/tr[4]/td/div/a/span").click()
    driver.find_element_by_id("ContentPlaceHolder1_GetNewPasswordPopup_EmailTB_I").send_keys("test@mail.com")
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='ContentPlaceHolder1_GetNewPasswordPopup_TPCFm1_GetPasswordButton_CD']/span").click()
    
change_password()

time.sleep(5)
driver.quit()
```

Comment: Do you mean running the above script multiple times?

Comment: @aykcandem yeah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this process

```py
for i in range(10):
    driver.get("http://nsagov.ru/Users/Login.aspx")
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/form/div[4]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr/td/div/table/tbody/tr[4]/td/div/a/span").click()
    driver.find_element_by_id("ContentPlaceHolder1_GetNewPasswordPopup_EmailTB_I").send_keys("test@mail.com")
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='ContentPlaceHolder1_GetNewPasswordPopup_TPCFm1_GetPasswordButton_CD']/span").click()
    driver.execute_script("window.open('');")
    time.sleep(2)
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[-1])
```

which create a new tab and follow the code again

Comment: I solved the problem with `while`, but I like your solution.  Without `#driver.execute_script("window.open('');")`